# Time Complexity - BigO Notation of Python's eval

Tags: python, time-complexity, big-o, eval

What is the time complexity of Python's eval for evaluating mathematical expressions? I cannot find any sources that state it. My assumption is that it is O(n) where n is the amount of operators in the expression.

If anyone has a reference to a site where this is stated, it would be much appreciated if you could share.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but wouldn't the time complexity be whatever the time complexity is of the expression being evaluated?  `eval` just takes an expression and parses and evaluates it as a Python expression.

Comment: @chrisz Yes, though I was wondering how it would do so with operator precedence and parentheses etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Operators have no time complexity. *Operations on values do*.

For example:

- `1 + 1` a time complexity of `O(1)`; adding two integers is simple <sup>(*)</sup>
- `[1, 2, 3] + [4, 5, 6]` has a different time complexity, `O(len([1, 2, 3]) + len([4, 5, 6])`, because concatenating two lists requires copying across all the references from both lists to a new list object. For the general case, `list_len_N + list_len_K` is a `O(N+K)` operation.

You can look up the time complexity of operations on common Python types in the [Python wiki](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity), plus some added common sense. For example, whenever an operation has to produce a new object, account for a copy. `+` on two lists produces a new list object, so it involves a copy and an extend operation.

When using multiple operators on different types, the normal rules of algorithmic complexity apply; complex operations in sequential operations are summed, but `O(N) + O(N)` is still linear `O(N)`.

---

<sup>*</sup> Python's integer type is unbound, so the time complexity is a little more complex as the internal C implementation of CPython can use N C  integers to represent the value. In practice, this is not an issue as the difference between adding small integers and big integers falls into nothingness compared to running an interpreter loop for a dynamic language.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Helped with clarifying things a lot

Comment: @Martijn Pieters regular operators are different inside strings and calling eval on it though isn't it? Are you saying x = eval("1+5*2") is the same time complexity as x = 1 + 5 * 2?

Comment: @BigDreamz: time complexity deals with how the time taken grows as a function of the number of inputs; changing a given expression A to use `eval('A')` instead **doesn't change how the algorithm handles inputs**. The cost of parsing the expression first is a fixed cost, it doesn't change change how the overall algorithm behaves with fewer or more values to work with.